# How to use jenkins variable as execute command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

```
        stage('Preparation') {
            steps {
                script{
                    if(Deployment == 'UAT'){
                        goals = 'mvn clean install -Denvironment=uat '
                        script_arg='''shutdown.sh uat | sleep 20 | startup.sh uat'''
                    }
                    else{
                        goals = 'mvn clean install -Denvironment=dev'
                        script_arg='''shutdown.sh dev | sleep 20 | startup.sh dev'''

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build') {
            steps{
                sh goals
            }
        }
        
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps([$class: 'BapSshPromotionPublisherPlugin']) {
                sshPublisher(
                    continueOnError: false, failOnError: true,
                    publishers: [
                        sshPublisherDesc(
                            configName: "ABC",
                            verbose: true,
                            transfers: [
                                sshTransfer(sourceFiles: "target/abcd.war",
                                removePrefix: "/target", 
                                remoteDirectory: "/remote", 
                                execCommand: '''shutdown.sh uat | sleep 20 | startup.sh uat''')

                            ]
                        )
                    ]
                )
            }
        }
```

I am new to jenkins. I am trying to setup a pipeline.
I have above code which is working fine but I want to pass execution command based on environment dev/uat
I have created variable script_arg in Preparation stage and want to use in Deploy stage as execCommand

deploy --> steps --> sshPublisher --> publishers --> sshPublisherDesc --> transfers

but when I substitute  it as below

```
execCommand: "${script_arg}"
```

This doesnot work.

Comment: Where have you added this execCommand?

Comment: deploy --> steps --> sshPublisher --> publishers --> sshPublisherDesc --> transfers

Comment: I am replacing execCommand present at above place with the code '${script_arg}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the variable outside the pipeline and see, something like below.

```
def script_arg

pipeline {
   stages {
        stage() {}
        stage() {}
        ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried but no luck. Am I mistaking in single quotes

Comment: I was mistaking in single quote  code needs to be usedd as execCommand:"${script_arg}"